# UIAlertView Textfield to Change UILabel Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

My app has a `UILabel`. I would like the user to be able to change the value of the label by pushing an "edit" button. I am able to implement a `UIAlertView` textfield with `alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`, but I am not sure how the `UILabel` will receive the new value that was entered by the user.

This is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)edit
{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit New Amount"
                                                    message:@"Enter new rate"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    [alert show];

    UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter New Rate";

}
```

I also implemented the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to change the label when the user presses "Ok" and have a reference to `UILabel *someLabel` as an ivar:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        // UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput will only ever have a single field at index 0
        UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

        someLabel.text = field.text;

    } else {
        // this is where you would handle any actions for "Cancel"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I make it so the alertView pops up when I push my edit button?

Comment: The line `[alert show];` should take care of that for you.  Are you sure that `edit` is even being called successfully?  Add a breakpoint or an `NSLog()` in there to be sure.

Comment: Ok, it's working now. I was confused how to use your code with mine. :) One more question... when I enter text in my AlertView Textfield, and I push OK, my UILabel simply disappears... do you know what I may have done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I just got it to work. I accidentally did not use all of code. It's working great now. I accepted your answer as the correct one.